# Merging multiple .txt files in .csv file line by line

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder with lots of .txt files. I want to merge all .txt file in a single .csv file line by line/row by row.

I have tried the following python codes, they work fine but I have to change .txt file name to add the content into .csv row.

```
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
raw_html = open('/home/erdal/Dropbox/Marburg/LA/LT_CORPUS/fsdl.txt')
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "lxml").text 
#print(cleantext)
print (re.sub('\s+',' ', cleantext))
#appending to csv as row
row = [re.sub('\s+',' ', cleantext)]
with open('LT_Corpus.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(row)
csvFile.close()
```

I expect to see better and faster solutions for automatizing the process without changing file names. Any recommendation is welcome.

Comment: I don't see you changing any file name in that code

Comment: os.listdir('PATH') will give you everything in a directory, you could then loop through each file and if the [-4:] == '.txt' you could then do the processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Accessing a list of filenames

The following should get you closer to what you want.

`import os` will give you access to the `os.listdir()` function that lists all the files in a directory. You may need to provide the path to your data folder, if the data files are not in the same folder as your script.

This should look something like: 
`os.listdir('/home/erdal/Dropbox/Marburg/LA/LT_CORPUS/')`

Using all the filenames in that directory, you can then open each one individually, by parsing through them with a `for` loop.

```
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import os

filenames = os.listdir('/home/erdal/Dropbox/Marburg/LA/LT_CORPUS/')
for file in filenames:
    raw_html = open('/home/erdal/Dropbox/Marburg/LA/LT_CORPUS/' + file)
    cleantext = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "lxml").text 
    output = re.sub('\s+',' ', cleantext)      # saved the result using a variable
    print(output)                              # the variable can be reused
    row = [output]                             # as needed, in different contexts 
    with open('LT_Corpus.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

**Several other nuances**: I removed the `csvfile.close()` function call at the end. When using `with` context managers, the context manager automatically closes the file for you when you leave the scope of the context manager code block (i.e. that indented section below the `with` statement). Having said this, there might be merit to simply opening the `csv` file, leaving it open, and then opening the `txt` files one by one and writing their content to the open `csv` and waiting to close the `csv` til the very end.

Comment: This was really helpful for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @erdalayan if you found it helpful, please indicate so by Accepting the answer and/or Upvoting the answer. To accept an answer: as the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the Up and Down vote arrows. Click the checkmark next to the post that best answers your question to accept that answer as the best one. To Upvote an answer, click the Up vote arrow. Much appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I did as you have mentioned. Sorry for that since I have not noticed that beforehand.