# Merging multiple/all files in folder line by line

Tags: python, csv, file, merge

I need to merge all my csv files in one adding them like columns.

I tried code based on the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889865/merging-multiple-txt-files-in-csv-file-line-by-line) but it didn't work. It put lines from one csv to one line in new csv and other csvs added as new lines.

My code:

```
import glob
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


for file in glob.glob('2023-02-10-upraveno/oh/pokus/??oh.csv'):
    raw_html = open(file)
    cleantext = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "lxml").text 
    output = re.sub('\s+',' ', cleantext)      # saved the result using a variable
    print(output)                              # the variable can be reused
    row = [output]                             # as needed, in different contexts 
    with open('Ohs.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

What I have:

multiple files with structure:

1. file

```
a,b
c,d
```

2. file (same data structure)

```
e,f
g,h
```

What I expect:

```
a,b,e,f,...
b,c,g,h,...
```

What I got by tried code:

```
"a,b c,d"
"e,f g,h"
```

Comment: Show your code as properly formatted text in the question, even if it didn't work correctly.

Comment: Include your code in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` to get all concurrent rows across all files and use list addition to concatenate the concurrent rows together

```
import csv
import glob
import itertools
import os


dirpath = "/path/to/directory/with/csv/files"
csvPaths = glob.glob(os.path.join(dirpath, "*.csv"))
csvs = [csv.reader(open(fpath) for fpath in csvPaths]
rows = itertools.zip_longest(*csvs, fillvalue=[])

with open(os.path.join(dirpath, 'output.csv'), 'w') as outfile:
    outfile = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in rows:
        outfile.writerow(sum(row, start=[]))
```

Comment: I tried it and I get an error at last line of code
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22584\4101395041.py in <module>
     13     outfile = csv.writer(outfile)
     14     for row in rows:
---> 15         outfile.writerow(sum(row))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

I understand that an error is that code is trying to sum integers and lists but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: @JanK: You're absolutely right! I'd forgotten to add the optional/default argument in there. Thanks for the bug report - answer updated :)

Comment: thank you very much, it works now! There is one missing parenthesis in csvs after open but that's not a big problem.